# Почему не присылает уведомления в андроид?

Tags: android, уведомления

Есть такой код, и он не присылает уведомления. Что делать?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"YOUR TAG");

    wl.acquire();


    Bundle extras= intent.getExtras();
   int idn = extras.getInt("id");


    Notification notification = new  Notification.Builder(context)
      .setContentTitle("Dream")
      .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("name"))
      .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(idn, notification);



    wl.release();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) вам надо указать канал уведомлений и маленькую иконку. Первое нужно, т.к. способ без указания канала не будет работать на ОС версии 8+, а второе - т.к. не будет работать вообще нигде без иконки.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "some string here, i.e. app package")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
```